# Lighweight redundant error correction & loss prevention of MIDI stream

Tags: error-handling, microcontroller, midi, wireless

I'd be very much interested hearing any tips on how
a simple algorithm can be implemented to overcome
lost packets of a binary stream.

I was considering doing something like

ABCDE,BCDEF,CDEFG,DEFGH,.....

or may be with 3 bytes instead of 5, i.e.

ABC,BCE,CDE,DEF,...

Though I'm not too sure of this.
I understand the basic principles behind
error correcting theory, but it doesn't
help a lot .. any suggestions ?

Comment: Re-tagged "networking" since you didn't mention IPv6 in the question. Are you using IPv6? I'm assuming you're using UDP. Can you go into more detail about what you mean by "overcome lost packets"? How does it impact your application to lose that data? If you need a reliable transport, why aren't you using TCP?

Comment: @Mike, he's talking about MIDI, which has *nothing* to do with TCP/IP. Don't retag if you don't know what the question is about.

Comment: @errordeveloper, to clarify, you are writing your own underlying transport protocol that will carry MIDI over it, correct?

Comment: @Nik, I down-scoped the tag from `ipv6` to `networking`. The question still sounds like it might be a "networking" question, but the OP needs to clarify. It sounded like the OP was trying to do "MIDI over IPv6", but didn't come out and say it. In which case "ipv6" is still too broad because the discussion would likely be around UDP/networking principles.

Comment: Basically I used TCP for now, and it works ok (despite the idea that TCP is bad for 6loWPAN). But I should probably use UDP and perhaps even UDP multicast. I've been reading RTP-MIDI RFC, though ..it's a bit too complicated for to implement right now. And probably will be very hard to squize into the MCU (on top of Contiki and uIP).

Comment: I have simple TCP app which works now, thought I should probably do it  in way similar to RTP-MIDI but simpler.

Comment: what I mean by "loss prevention" is really some sort of redundancy - so a stream could be still recovered if a packet has been lost; basically just to prevent "stuck notes" in the music performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found what I was looking for - it's the Convolutional
Coding that need to use in this sort of application. It looks like
the most suitable coding technique for a low-power application.

For those who interested in updates on this, I'll write more on my
[project's wiki](http://wmi.new-synth.info/projects/wmi/wiki/Additional_New_Topics)

There is an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code) on Wikipedia whcih has a [nice diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/84/Convolutional_encoder_recursive.svg).